# Hosting Java based REST API services

Tags: java, rest, hosting

I have build REST APIs for Database(local postgres SQL db) CRUD operations using Java/JPA/Spring/Hibernate. Everything is working fine with my local tomcat server deployment. Now would like to build a mobile app using these REST services.

I have basic question/suggestion to know where I can deploy this war file so that I can access from my mobile device. I was reading about Google APP engine and AWS. But could not understand if I need to write any Proprietary code to deploy to these service providers ? Any free/paid hosting server suggestion where I can just deploy war without adding any host specific proprietary code.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a virtual machine with Ubuntu Linux. I have a similar technology stack. Java, JAX-RS, Hibernate, PostgreSQL. I use the Tomcat and PostgreSQL packages provided by Ubuntu. The product name of the virtual machine is [JiffyBox](https://www.df.eu/de/cloud-hosting/cloud-server/). You can choose between various Linux distributions. It is offered by [Domain Factory](https://www.df.eu/) in Germany and Austria.

For what I know about Google App Engine it uses the Servlet 2.5 Standard as is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/). For data storage you can use JPA as is stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore). But they do recommend using their own Objectify API as can be read [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview).

For AWS I don't know. I just took a quick look. It seems you need to use their [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sdk-for-java/). I can't find anything refering to Servlets in the [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html).